# socket.io refresh list of connected clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

At the moment I have a websocket server that generates a uuid for every connection made to it and passes that onto the client, and on the client side I update a simple list with all the connections. I'd like to see the original connaction's list refreshed, let me illustrate what I mean:

1. open a tab - the first client connects and I see my uuid on the
   list
2. I open a new tab, connect to the websocket, I see the
   previously connected ID and the new ID
3. Now, when I go back to tab
   1, I don't see both connections, only the first one that was there.
   How can I refresh this list, in a way such that if a websocket
   connection made, this list of uuid's is refreshed for all the
   connected clients.

My code at the moment is the following:

server:

```
var http = require("http"), io = require("socket.io"), uuid = require ("node-uuid");
var connectedPlayers = new Array();
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) { 
  // Send HTML headers and message
  res.writeHead(200,{ "Content-Type": "text/html" }); 
  res.end("<h1>Server is ready & listening</h1>");
});
server.listen(1222, "1.1.1.1");

var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.set('log level', 0);

socket.on("connection", function(client) {
  client.on("connection", function(){
    console.log("Client connected.");
  });

  client.on("disconnect",function(client){
    //connected--;
    console.log("Client disconnected.");
  });

  client.userid = uuid();
  console.log(client.userid);
  connectedPlayers.push(client.userid);
  client.emit("onconnected", {playersId: connectedPlayers});
});
```

client:

```
var socket = io.connect("1.1.1.1:1222");

        console.log(socket);
        socket.on("connect",function() {
            console.log("Client has connected to the server");
        });

        socket.on("disconnect",function() {
            console.log("The client has disconnected from the server");
        });

        socket.on("error", function(message) {
            console.log("It is not possible to connect to the server: " + message);
        });

        socket.on("onconnected", function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.playersId.length; i++)
                $("#players").append("<li>" + data.playersId[i] + "</li>");
        });
```

(and of course: `<ul id="players"></ul>`)

Comment: change client.emit to socket.emit or maybe broadcast()

Comment: I've changed to socket.emit() but my client doesn't seem to pick up anything, the "onconnected" function is never called on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to emit the event using 'io.sockets.emit' and not 'client.emit'.

Change your last line in the server script from:

```
  client.emit("onconnected", {playersId: connectedPlayers});
```

to:

```
  socket.sockets.emit("onconnected", {playersId: connectedPlayers});
```

To add the values in the list, my way looks like this:

```
socket.on("onconnected", function(data) {
    var tmp = document.getElementById("players");
    for (var i in data.playersId)
        tmp.innerHTML += "<li>" + data.playersId[i] + "</li>";
});
```

Comment: I think I am missing something:index.js:26 io.sockets.emit("onconnected", {playersId: connectedPlayers}); ^ TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined

Comment: Try changing ´socket.on("connection", function(client) {´ for ´io.sockets.on("connection", function(client) {´

Comment: Then I get: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

Comment: oh, i see you are using 'var socket=io.listen(server)' where I usually use 'io = io.listen(server)'. Then, I think it should work with socket.sockets.on("connection",...) and socket.sockets.emit(...). Hope this time is ok.

Comment: It does indeed, thank you Riwels. However, it still doesn't solve my original problem. Tab 1's list is still not updated, I assume I'd have to force a refresh for the list, right?

Comment: No, you don't need to reload. I'm updating content with something like: socket.on("event",function(data){
 var tmp = document.getElementById("mid_center_canvas");
 tmp.innerHTML += data.content;});
      }

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit dumb. It just works...I made a typo.  Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated.